# bash file, mysql command update syntax error

Tags: mysql, cron, syntax-error, sh, mysql-error-1064

Hi I want to make a script I can run via cron to update certain columns on a schedule

The script command not running it in sh file works fine

```
UPDATE `lines` SET allowed_outputs = '[1,2]';
```

in the sh file I've  added it like this

```
mysql --user="username" --password="pass" --database="data" -s --execute="UPDATE 'lines' SET allowed_outputs = '[1,2]';"
```

but I get an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''lines' SET allowed_outputs = '[1,2]'' at line 1
```

i'm sure its something to do with 'lines'

i've also tried backtags aswell

```
mysql --user="username" --password="pass" --database="data" -s --execute="UPDATE `lines` SET allowed_outputs = '[1,2]';"
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET allowed_outputs = '[1,2]'' at line 1
```

Comment: do you have an example on how it will look

Comment: The shell is interpreting the back-ticks as command substitution, i.e. it's trying to run the shell command `lines` and use the output of that command as your table name. This command apparently has no output, so your SQL statement looks like `UPDATE  SET allowed_outputs = ...`.

Comment: There is a way you can reference the table name without delimiting it at all, even though `lines` is a reserved keyword. Use a qualified identifier: `UPDATE data.lines SET allowed_outputs = ...`. By qualifying the table with its schema name, it makes it clear it's not the reserved keyword.